# What's a good work flow web or desktop app?

Tags: web-application, diagrams

I'm looking for an application where I can draw workflows, a bit similar to a flow chart diagram but more loose with the rules.  For instance, a typical workflow to ask a question here is:

```
Search for keywords to question
  |
If not found
  |
Ask question
  |
Wait for answer
  |
Read list of answers
  |
Accept the best
```

I would like each of the above item to be enclosed within a rectangle.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tried Firefox Pencil and Balsamiq Mockups.  I can use their existing widgets to meet my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Visio, Word, PowerPoint, even Excel can do what you want.

I created this simple flowchart in Visio in less time than it took to create the screenshot and upload it:

[image: flowchart]

Answer (score 1):

Just to pipe up with some more options... [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia) is a free application that runs on a handful of platforms.

Two browser based options would be [Gliffy.com](http://www.gliffy.com/) and [flowchart.com](http://www.flowchart.com/).

Comment: Dia is a textbook example of software usability disaster...

Answer (score 0):

[MindMeister](http://www.mindmeister.com/) is a free online mind mapping web application.  You can use "mind-mapping" software to map business or programming logic pretty easily, so I would give that a try.  From the [looks of it](http://www.mindmeister.com/home/editions), it seems that the free edition would do basically everything you need.

*Disclaimer: I have never actually used that site*

Answer (score 0):

It makes more sense using a mindmap - [FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is your friend. Free, open source, and cross-platform.

[image]

Comment: And it exports to many, many different formats, all ready for you to use with almost anything, and communicate your workflows/ideas with anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Also maybe [Diagram Designer](http://www.meesoft.com/) (3 cows on tucows.com):

> Includes a customizable template
>   object palette, spell-checker, simple
>   graph plotter to plot mathematical
>   expressions and an advanced "pocket"
>   calculator with equation solver. It
>   uses compressed file format for
>   minimizing drawing file size.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Altova UModel](http://www.altova.com/umodel/activity-diagrams.html), but I think UML would be too strict for your needs...

[image]
<sup>**UML Activity Diagram** (Click image to enlarge)</sup>

And it's not free... UML knowledge isn't really required to use it, although it does help a bit. (It can do reverse engineering, which can be useful sometimes.)